# Swing - Strings externalizing not working

Tags: java, string, swing, internationalization

I'm trying to externalize string to English with the Window Builder from Swing but it's not working at all. For this I'm going to the design tab and selecting the "World Icon". Then I select all the strings and English as the New locale and translate stuff. Then in the class that is created I make the `getLocale` and `setIdioma` methods to do all the job but it doesn't seem to be working for some reason...

My code for the `main frame` is:

```
package presentacion;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Prueba {

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Prueba window = new Prueba();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Prueba() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
        gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);

        JLabel lblPrueba = new JLabel(Messages.getString("Prueba.lblPrueba.text")); //$NON-NLS-1$
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblPrueba = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblPrueba.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_lblPrueba.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblPrueba.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(lblPrueba, gbc_lblPrueba);

        JButton btnJeje = new JButton(Messages.getString("Prueba.btnJeje.text")); //$NON-NLS-1$
        btnJeje.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Messages.setIdioma("inglés");
            }
        });
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnJeje = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnJeje.gridx = 1;
        gbc_btnJeje.gridy = 4;
        panel.add(btnJeje, gbc_btnJeje);
    }

}
```

Code for `Messages.java`:

```
package presentacion;

import java.beans.Beans;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.MissingResourceException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Messages {

    private Messages() {

    } 

    private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "presentacion.messages"; //$NON-NLS-1$
    private static ResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE = loadBundle();
    private static ResourceBundle loadBundle() {
        return ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME);
    }

    public static String getString(String key) {
        try {
            ResourceBundle bundle = Beans.isDesignTime() ? loadBundle() : RESOURCE_BUNDLE;
            return bundle.getString(key);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            return "!" + key + "!";
        }
    }

    private static Locale getLocale(String appIdioma){
        Locale locale = new Locale("es");
        if (appIdioma.equals("inglés"))
            locale = new Locale("en");
        return locale;
    }

    public static void setIdioma(String idioma){
        RESOURCE_BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME, getLocale(idioma));
    }
}
```

And then the file `messages.properties` . There's also `messages_en.properties` with the same but the strings are in English so it's not worth posting IMO.

```
Prueba.btnJeje.text=Inglés
Prueba.lblPrueba.text=Prueba
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Define "it doesn't seem to be working", precisely. What are you doing? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Where are the messaages.properties files located in your project?

Comment: To change or "translate" the texts like the label and button since it's strings externalitation as title says. messages.properties is in the same package (presentacion) as the other files

Comment: You answered the last of my 4 questions. Now answer the 3 others.

Comment: 1. Trying to translate it when pressing the button. 2. The texts to be translated to english. 3. Nothing. 4. In same package as the rest, presentacion.

Comment: When you press the button, all you're doing is to call `Messages.setIdioma("inglés");`. You don't change the text of the button and label. So their text won't change.

Comment: isn't setIdioma supposed to change it itself? I've never done this, what should I do then?

Comment: No. setIdioma(), as your code shows, only changes the value of RESOURCE_BUNDLE. It doesn't set the text of any button or label. If you want to change the text of a button, call button.setText(). Same for a label.

Comment: whats all this for then if I can just create a method to change al texts with setText?

Comment: What's all *what* for? A ResourceBundle allows getting an i18ned message, i.e. a String, based on a locale. What you do with the String you get is up to you, and the bundle doesn't care. Whether you pass that String to a JButton constructor or a JLabel setText() method is irrelevant for the resource bundle. And assigning a new value to a static RESOURCE_BUNDLE variable won't magicall change the text of all your buttons and labels. If you buy milk at the grocery, and the grocery decides to put soda cans where the bottles of milk previously were, your bottle of milk won't become a soda can.

Comment: Okay I know what's going now, lets hope I can explain myself so we can do this :( . Apparently what I did works for example if i call that new frame from another one with the Bundle being changed. But what I want is to press the button from that same frame and that the text get changed in runtime. Isn't it possible to do this without setText? like something like repainting the frame texts or something?

Comment: No,  it's not possible. repainint the frame won't recall the constructors of your button and label, where the text is passed to the buttons.

Comment: Well, I think a kind of fix would be disposing that frame and creating it again when pressing the button, I tested that and worked. How should I close this thread? Do I add my own answer? I'm new to SO sorry

Comment: Yes, you can add your own answer. Or you can delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I made sort of a solution to do this on run-time as I wanted to. To do so I just disposed the frame I'm calling the method from and create an instance from that same frame:

Constructor changed to:

```
public Prueba() {
        initialize();
        frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Button listener changed to:

```
btnJeje.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Messages.setIdioma("inglés");
                frame.dispose();
                new Prueba();
}
```